# Путь к фотографии через //static.site.net

Tags: img, href

есть сайт `zara.com`, у них картинки хорошего качества и добавлены так, что за путь? И как вообще желательно хранить картинки на сайте?

```
//static.zara.net/photos///2018/V/1/2/p/2308/302/040/2/w/1024/2308302040_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1516793309729
```

Comment: Хранить можно как Вам удобно. Если их не много и с ними особо ничего не надо делать (кроме показа) то думаю папочки images достаточно. А если у вас какой то сервис, обрабатывающий фото, то думаю стоит подумать о структуре хранения

Comment: понял спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

`https://site.com` - это можно заменить на `//site.com`